# Java quartz suddenly stop firing events

Tags: java, batch-file, quartz-scheduler

I am using quartz to schedule a daily batch process, and it runs the first days, but it had happened that fires the event for 2 days or so, and then, it stops firing the job.

The java version i'm using is: 
java version "1.7.0_25"
Quartz version (in POM):
    
            org.quartz-scheduler
            quartz
            2.2.1

Here is my code:

Main function for the batch:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        SimpleDateFormat sd=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); 
        JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(MyJobClass.class).withIdentity("MyJobClass", "group1").build(); 
        Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
                .newTrigger()
                .withIdentity("MyTrigger", "group1") 
                .withSchedule(
                    SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule()
                        .withIntervalInHours(24).repeatForever())
                .startAt(sd.parse("2015-01-12 07:30:00")) 
                .build();

        Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
        scheduler.start();
        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);

        String strLog="Batch initiated on " + new Date();
        System.out.println(strLog);
        log.info(strLog);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        //log error
    } 


}
```

And here is my execute method in the job:

```
public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
    generateBatchProcess();
}

public void generateBatchProcess(){

   try{
      //do lots of interesting stuff, calling MyBatis Daos, generating excel files and sending an email
   }catch (Exception e){
      //log error
   }
}
```

Does someone have an idea of why this happens? Is it the garbage collector something to do with this?

Comment: Can you confirm whether any error is being logged?

Comment: That's preciselly the problem. I haven't seen any error. As long as I have seen, the event is not being fired.

Comment: Looking back at your code, have you thought about using catch(Throwable t) instead of catch(Exception e)?  There are Errors that can be thrown that are not Exceptions.  I do not think I can be much more help.

Comment: Did you resolve this? I am facing the same issue. The jobs randomly stops triggering.

Comment: Well, i am ashamed of this because it was a "Bad programmer exception", I had a call to a database connection outside the try block that I hadn't seen before, then I could see the log error and solved it. I'm afraid that if that's not your case then I would need your code in order to help you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm ashamed to admit it was only a "BadProgrammerException" because I had a call to a database connection outside the try...catch block that i hadn't seen before, so the problem was that I was not reaching the database and I couldn't figure it out with the log information (the database connection was intermitent). After I found this out, I corrected the database issue and quartz worked ok.